# Is there any any 802.11AC card that will work in X230?

Tags: bios, thinkpad, 802.11ac, whitelist

Lenovo Thinkpad X230 BIOS [embeds a whitelist of WLAN cards](http://change.org/petitions/lenovo-release-an-unencumbered-version-of-the-bios). If a card is not in the whitelist, it is rejected by the laptop.

Are there any 802.11ac cards that would work on Lenovo Thinkpad X230?

Comment: It has to be published, or they will provided it upon request, otherwise what could does it do?  But I can guarantee you that given that 802.11ac is not even finalized yet the chances of one being on that list is very unlikely

Comment: It stops you from buying a card unless they sell it to you, or the vendor pays to advertise it as being Lenovo approved.

Comment: @Ramhound - what the whitelist actually does is keep FCC from complaining, because they can't just certify the card or just laptop, they have to certify laptop+card together, because laptop provides the antenna sets.

Comment: That's nonsense, but nice try!

Comment: It's true, since the EIRP is affected by both power and antenna gain.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

No, but that wouldn't stop you from installing one.

## Official Way

The official [whitelist](https://download.lenovo.com/parts/ThinkPad/x230t_fru_bom_20121010.pdf) for Lenovo Thinkpad X230 contains only 4 wireless NICs ("WLAN"s, "wireless cards"), *none* of which is 802.11ac:

- [60Y3233](https://www.cheeverind.com/60Y3233.html) -- Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6300 WLAN -- [802.11a/b/g/n](http://www.thinkpad-parts.com/60Y3233-ThinkPad.html)
- [60Y3247](https://www.cheeverind.com/60Y3247.html) -- Wireless LAN Mini-PCI E420/E425 -- [802.11b/g/n](http://www.thinkpad-parts.com/60Y3247-ThinkPad.html)
- [60Y3249](https://www.cheeverind.com/60Y3249.html) -- Wireless LAN Mini-PCI E420/E425 -- [802.11b/g/n](http://www.thinkpad-parts.com/60Y3249-ThinkPad.html)
- [60Y3253](https://www.cheeverind.com/60Y3253.html) -- Intel Centrino N-6205 Wifi Card -- [802.11a/b/g/n](http://www.thinkpad-parts.com/60Y3253-ThinkPad.html)

## Unofficial Way

BIOS for Lenovo Thinkpad X230 can be replaced with an "unlocked" version, overriding the whitelist completely and allowing you to install any [physically compatible](https://ark.intel.com/products/75439/Intel-Dual-Band-Wireless-AC-7260) WLAN card, including 802.11ac ones.
The path isn't that easy, but if you *really* want the feature, here is a list of steps:

- [Obtain a modded version of the latest BIOS](https://www.bios-mods.com/forum/Thread-REQUEST-Lenovo-Thinkpad-X230-i-G2ETxxWW-Whitelist-Removal)
- Obtain a BIOS flashing kit (something like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=CH341A))
- Disassemble the laptop
- Flash the laptop using the kit
- Replace the Wi-Fi card with the new one